# Using "each loop variables" inside if statement in SASS

Tags: if-statement, sass, each

I am trying to generate a bunch of styles through an each loop in SASS. The styles should only be generated, if the variable the each loop is looking at right now is set.

I tried different variable "styles", e.g.: $use-#{$type}, but I'm kinda lost. Even tried to do it with a function, but it seems like functions can not access the variables of loops.

```
$typo: (t1, t2);

$use-t1: 1; $t1-color: black;
$use-t2: 1; $t2-color: black;

@each $type in $typo{
  @if $#{use-$type} == 1{ 
    .#{$type}{
      color: $#{$type}-color;
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect the variables in the first round of the each loop to be:

- $#{use-$type} -> $use-t1 -> 1
- $#{$type}-color -> $t1-color -> black

But both throw "Expected identifier." or "Unknown variable", depending on how I try it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference a variable using interpolation – in your case `$#{$type}-color`.
I would recommend you to use a map instead – like:

```
  $map: (
    t1: (use: 1, color: black),
    t2: (use: 2, color: white)    
  );


  @each $key, $value in $map {
    @if map-get($value, use) == 1 {
      .#{$key} { color: map-get($value, color); }    
    }
  }

  // output 
  .t1 { color: black; }
```

As a side note it's worth knowing Sass will not print properties with null values or classes without properties – why you can do the above without checking `use`

```
  $map: (
    t1: (color: black),
    t2: (color: null)    // no color => no prop => empty class => nothing printed  
  );
  @each $key, $value in $map {
    .#{$key} { color: map-get($value, color); }    
  }


  // output 
  .t1 { color: black; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Will try right now. I knew that "null" will lead to the property not being printed, but that was a simplification of what I was trying (There is a "use" and a "force" and also it is not applied to one but on many properties which have standard values)

Comment: @ValentinHuwer If his answer helped you, be sure and select the checkmark next to his answer so he gets credit for it. You will as well